# STM32F discovery doesn't execute code after programming successfully

Tags: stm32, embedded, programming, stm32f4

I have a stm32f051R8T6 Discovery board, and I compiled a simple blinking LED code to activate the LED's on the board itself. The code builds successfully and flashes the MCU but the MCU won't execute the code, I have reset it and tried programming it with a different code which worked in the past but still no luck, I am working in Coocox.

Once I have the hex file I flash the MCU with either the STM32 st-link unity or Coocox itself and both say it flashes successfully

I think the MCU is held under reset but I'm not sure and I don't know how to get it out.

THe link to the manual is here: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/30/ae/6e/54/d3/b6/46/17/DM00050135.pdf/files/DM00050135.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00050135.pdf

Code is Below

```
#include "stm32f0xx.h"

void delay(const int d);

int main(void)
{
  // GPIOC Periph clock enable
  RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOCEN;

  // PC8 and PC9 in output mode
  GPIOC->MODER |= (GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0);

  // Push pull mode selected
  GPIOC->OTYPER &= ~(GPIO_OTYPER_OT_8 | GPIO_OTYPER_OT_9);

  // Maximum speed setting
  GPIOC->OSPEEDR |= (GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR8 | GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR9);

  // Pull-up and pull-down resistors disabled
  GPIOC->PUPDR &= ~(GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR8 | GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR9);

  while(1)
  {
    // Set PC9
    GPIOC->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BS_9;
    // Reset PC8
    GPIOC->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR_8;
    // Delay ~ 1 sec.
    delay(SystemCoreClock/8);

    // Reset PC9
    GPIOC->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR_9;
    // Set PC8
    GPIOC->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BS_8;
    // Delay ~ 1 sec.
    delay(SystemCoreClock/8);
  }
}

void delay(const int d)
{
  volatile int i;

  for(i=d; i>0; i--){ ; }

  return;
}
```

Comment: What kind of debug equipment do you have? Multimeter? Oscilloscope? Logic analyzer?

Comment: I have a Multimeter and an Oscilloscope available

Comment: If you try to flash one of the example projects it doesn't work either? Can you run the code in debug mode to see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lay with the Coocox library files, what I did was uninstall the program and re-installed it and it worked successfully.